# Can I make caramel sauce with crystalline fructose?

Tags: sugar, caramel, caramelization, sugar-free

I'd like to make a caramel sauce with crystalline fructose as my mom's diabetic and can't have sugar.

I know (in theory) that fructose caramelizes at a lower temp than regular sugar, but I'm not sure if caramelizing crystalline fructose would lead to a similar taste and if I should do it the same way as if I were using sugar.

Thank you v much :)

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: I think you should check with a doctor. I believe your premise is wrong. Diabetics need to control carbohydrates in general, not just sugar.

Comment: Mom's on insulin and we check in every three months with the doctor. She's had diabetes for over five years, plus a slew of other issues. So, thank you for your concern, but I'm well aware of what diabetes involves and requires. 

And, just for the record, the caramel sauce is for a no-bake cheesecake I've already modified to be diabetes-friendly, except that I make it with lemon curd and wanted to try something different for Xmas - namely an apple caramel cheesecake.

Answer (score 1):

It won't caramelize, it doesn't have the same properties as sugar.

What you can do is brown butter, cook it with cream, and flavor it with vanilla and crystalline fructose to approximate caramel. I haven't tried this, there are a variety of "diabetic caramel sauce" recipes you can google.

Comment: Thank you. And I have Googled but many of those recipes use sweeteners that I can't find locally.

My other idea was to try to make something like a pastry cream and flavor it with sugar-free Torani Caramel syrup. Guess I'll be going that route.